# $ not defined using jQuery in WordPress

Tags: jquery

I know that jQuery is loaded, because I can switch out the `$` for 'jQuery' and everything behaves as expected, but this will be a messy script if I can't fix this

This script:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.vimeo_desc_feed li a").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    })
});
```

Produces the error **`$ is not a function`**

This script:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("ul.vimeo_desc_feed li a").click(function(){
        alert(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    })
});
```

works fine.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can wrap your javascript inside a self-invoking function, then pass `jQuery` as an argument to it, using `$` as the local variable name. For example:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.vimeo_desc_feed li a").click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr('href'));
      return false;
    })
 });
}(jQuery));
```

should work as intended.

If I remember correctly the WP-supplied version of jQuery (the one you get if you `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`) puts jQuery in no-conflict immediately, causing `$` to be undefined.

Comment: aah, I see. I used to add it by hand, which explains why I have not come across this issue.

Comment: Thank you, I was using the alternate format with jQuery at the beginning instead of end.. but couldn't figure out how to return a value, with this format I just added return before the self-invoking function, and it works.

Comment: Very useful answer.

Answer (score 32):

You're almost there!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("ul.vimeo_desc_feed li a").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    })

});
```

You have to pass a reference to jQuery as the `$` function into your method or it won't work.  If you just place a $ inside the first `function()` call as I did above, things will be working just fine.

Comment: +1: That is more readable than putting `jQuery`at the end.

Comment: ...but it isn't the standard way of doing an anonymous function.  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-anonymous-function-calls

Comment: Yes and no.  They're both considered "standard" ways of doing it.  One creates a singleton class that has `$` defined locally.  The other just defines a handler for the document's `ready` event and passes the jQuery object into the handler as `$`.  If you're trying to hook on to the `ready` event, the second method is more widely used.  If you need jQuery for any other purpose (to hook on to `$.browser` for example), you'd use a singleton class.

Comment: +1 for jQuery(document).ready(function($){...
mor infos about jquery and WordPress can you also read on my post: http://wpengineer.com/2028/small-tips-using-wordpress-and-jquery/ .

Answer (score 6):

Passing a function to jQuery is shorthand for `$(document).ready(...)` then by placing `$` as the first parameter of your callback, you create an alias for jQuery within that callback:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("ul.vimeo_desc_feed li a").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can see the documentation for this [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).