# Firebug says jQuery is loaded but $() and jQuery() are not defined

Tags: jquery, include

I'm trying to test my wordpress page with some simple jQuery script but it won't work.

I've loaded the script with `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` in `functions.php` as explained in the [wordpress guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_default_WordPress_script_from_a_non-default_location) but something's buggy.

I'm testing the page using `FireBug` installed in `Firefox 4` and if I take a look to the loaded scripts list it's all ok, but it also return me the error `jQuery is not defined` too.

I've followed the instructions on the `noConflict` mode but it still won't work for me:

```
// functions.php
<?php
    function init_scripts () {
        if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        } 
    }
    add_action('init', 'init_scripts');
?>

// header.php
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('hello?');
        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Where I'm wrong?

I've tried [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-is-not-working-in-wordpress-solution/) too and it's says jQuery object is not defined here:

```
// jquery from ajax.googleapis.com is correctly loaded
$j=jQuery.noConflict(); // firebug says jQuery is not defined by here

$j(document).ready(function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery needs to be outside the wrapper like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('hello?');
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

#### Edit:

***A better way would be:***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

Also make sure any inline script tags are ***AFTER*** your call to `wp_head();`

***And even better way:***

Instead of adding your script tags inline create a functions.js file containing all your extra functions etc.  Enqueue it with jQuery as a dependency.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'c3m_enqueue_scripts' );
function c3m_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-functions', TEMPLATEPATH .'/path/to/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ) TRUE);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-functions' );
}
```

Comment: this should be exactly what I've wrote, or is there something I've missed?

Comment: I changed `}(jQuery));` to `})(jQuery);`

Comment: yep! than kyou, but the problema remains jQuery is not defined and the alert won't work, Firebug still find the jquery.js file...

Comment: @vittorio see updates.  Your script must be loading before jquery somehow.  Is is above or below wp_head() in your header.php?

Comment: You found the problem! it was `wp_head(); written at the bottom of the header`... I've just listened to the [wordpress guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head), so it's wrong.

Comment: I didn't think it was a problem with the wrapper because really all of them should work as long as jquery is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

Your init call is correct, it will load jQuery where the wp_head() call is in your header.php file.

*after* the wp_head() call in your header.php file, add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    alert('hello?');
  });
</script>
```

placing the $ inside the function() section will allow you to use the regular $ with no conflicts.

Comment: I tried this way too, but the error still remain jQuery is not defined, I want to flag that is `jQuery`var is not defined instead of `$`, this sounds very strange for me.

Comment: There must be something else going on then.  I know the above code works, because it's my standard when I develop WP themes, and the above is what I use all the time.  There must be something else blocking it from working properly.  Have you swapped themes and turned off all your plugins to see if any of those things are causing the conflict?

Comment: thanks for the help, this is my first installation with wordpress, and everything went fine but this. I've changed the default theme with one I've started to design, `css` works, base functions works, I haven't wrote every layout page yet like side bar and other components, only `index.php`, `header.php`, `footer.php`, `functions.php`, css and the preview image for the theme. As I said everything works perfect but `jQuery` don't. I've also to say I'm running it on a `local web server`, I've tested `cakephp` apps and other but never saw this problem.