# Javascript stopped working

Tags: jquery, javascript

For some reason, the scripts that I have set up on my wordpress install stopped working yesterday afternoon. I had been editing things, but I'm not sure what I could have done that caused it to stop.

Is there any way that I can error check why it's not working, or any common reasons why it might not be?

The site is up at

http://www.delsilencio.net/staging/wordpress/

Comment: You need to add more information. Is it all JS, or what?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange. Please take the time to read our [How to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). **We** cannot figure out which scripts worked before. What _does_ work is your browser update nag – not very useful. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, and sorry for the vagueness. 
When I first asked this, I thought that it was all javascript that was not working- after Toscho pointed out that the browser update script was working, I realized that it was just jquery scripts that weren't working- specifically, queryloader2 and MP3 Jplayer. Which leads me to believe that something is wrong with the way I'm calling jquery, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: My source shows that it's being called with
`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.delsilencio.net/staging/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>`

Answer (score 0):

[One of your scripts](http://www.delsilencio.net/staging/wordpress/wp-content/themes/silencio/loader.js) doesn’t use jQuery correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {}
```

This cannot work because [jQuery runs in no conflict mode in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress). To make it work change the script to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {}
```

Comment: I don't think it's that, because even after changing the loader.js file to `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {` it still doesn't work...even removing loader.js and queryloader2.js from the header completely, the third jquery script still doesn't work. (MP3 Jplayer)

Comment: Changing the way I loaded the queryloader2.js and loader.js scripts fixed those two. I had it loaded with a path, and I changed that using <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>. However, the jplayer script is still not working. I'll keep trying though!