# Wordpress video end function

Tags: jquery, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$ not defined using jQuery in Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress)

I need to trigger a alert box when video ends

THis is the code i got from google

```
<script>
$("iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']").bind("ended", function() {
alert("I'm done!");
 });
</script>
```

I am just using the oembed function of wordpress to play youtube videos

I dont now why there are not working

Comment: Voted to close as off topic, this is a Youtube player issue, not a WordPress issue. The embed itself is defined by Youtube, as is the API, as is the JS, as is the player controls. This is a Javascript question should belongs on the main Stack Overflow site

Comment: i added here becuase 
the script works in normall php sites but doesnt works in wordpress as wordpress is using o-embed function to embed videos

Comment: So it is not a WordPress issue it's an OEmbed issue? Then it's still offtopic

Answer (score 0):

You can track the state of the youtube video, do you have the link to the youtube video? Use this youtube API function to get the result, and if it hits you back with a "0" you can initiate the alert(); function

```
player.getPlayerState():Number
```

Returns the state of the player. Possible values are unstarted (-1), ended (0), playing (1), paused (2), buffering (3), video cued (5).