# Load external javascript files

Tags: javascript

I have some trouble with loading external javascript files inside my WordPress theme.
Use the following markup:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The above code is set inside the `<head>` of my `header.php` file of my WordPress theme.

Why is this not working? Or should I also use the following for link external scripts?

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-sweet-script', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/script.js', array('jquery') );
}
```

Thank you.
Casper

Answer (score 1):

You should **always** use `wp_enqueue_script()` only, so other scripts can rely on yours or bundle all scripts in one file.

Do not load another jQuery; WordPress comes with a built-in jQuery, and other plugins and the core depend on exactly that version.

`wp_enqueue_script()` accepts any valid URL as source file, external or internal. If something doesn't work check your [browser's error console](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors). Note you have to [use `jQuery`, not `$`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress) in your scripts to access the global jQuery object.