# jQuery does not work on WordPress editor

Tags: jquery, visual-editor, wp-editor

I've added some content to WP's editor, however the new content does not respond to the click behaviour. Here's how I've added the content:

`add_filter( 'default_content', 'custom_editor_content' );`

Then created my function `custom_editor_content`:

```
function custom_editor_content( $content ) 
{

$content = '

<button id="test">Add</button>

...';

echo $content;

}
```

The content is displayed within the editor ok, but it doesn't respond to the jQuery that's being loaded like:

`add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'fnEnqueueAdminScripts' ) );`

The js loads ok, so does the content, but I cannot understand why the click function doesn't work. Here's my js:

```
$( "#test" ).click(function() {

    alert( "Test" );

});
```

Other snippets of js in the same file does work. The problem seems to be with the click function. The content is not generated dynamically so I don't think is a question of using `on` such as

```
$("#test").on("click", function() {

    alert("test");

});
```

Any ideas of what I've done wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress)?

Comment: `default_content` should `return` its value, not `echo`, otherwise the content will not be within the editor.

Comment: @tosho - yes, I did check whether the issue was related to non-conflict jQuery, so I did try both ways (using $ and jQuery), but the problem persists.

Comment: @Milo - I did change to return, however it didn't affect the jQuery situation - still doesn't work. any more suggestions?

Comment: I would guess that you'll have to make this work via the TinyMCE API, when the page loads the editor doesn't yet exist, and when it does get initialized it's within an iframe, so can't be targeted with a simple selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery code is using the $ symbol without accounting for noConflict mode.

More information:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers