# retrieving page content per AJAX

Tags: ajax, page-template

I am currently working on a single page website. I am trying to retrieve the page content via AJAX.

The page URL is `http://mylocalserver/sad/wp/clients`.

```
    $.get( 'http://mylocalserver/sad/wp/wp-admin/wp-ajax.php', 
          { 
           'action' : 'retrieve_content',
           'page_title' : 'clients'
          }, function( response ){
            if ( !response.error ) {
              alert ('AJAX request made! The post title is ' + response.post_title );
            } else {
              alert ('error: ' + response.error );    
            }
        });
```

in my php functions.php

```
    function retrieve_content(){
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'clients' );
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
    var_dump($content);
    exit();
     }
```

It says *Page not found*, whereas if I visit the page via URL the content appears.
I have hard coded the page title in the PHP function as-well.

Comment: Have you read [$ not defined using jQuery in Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress)?

Comment: its not the problem with jquery ajax.

Comment: What is the server's response to the ajax call ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the $ not defined, toscho comment was right