# inner jQuery won't work

Tags: jquery

i'm enqueuing jQuery with `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );`

(i see

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

in the resulting html page)

now, i'm tryin to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

and it only works if i add a jQuery reference manually (`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`)

do i miss something?

Comment: see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress/2896#2896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#showmenu').click(function() {
            jQuery('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Wordpress hates the `$` statement. If you replace it with `jQuery`, it should work.