# Using jQuery safe mode in WP?

Tags: theme-development, themes, jquery

I am pretty new in WordPress and I know just a litle about jQuery and Javascript and I have the following problem:

Into my **functions.php** file I load **jQuery**, the jQuery **FlexSlider** pluging (that create a slideshow) and another personal **jQuery** scripts file, in this way:

```
/* Function automatically executed by the hook 'load_java_scripts':
 * 1) Load all my JavaScripts
 */
function load_java_scripts() {

    // Load jQuery:
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // Load FlexSlider JavaScript
    wp_enqueue_script('flexSlider-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js', array('jquery'), 'v2.1', true);
    // Load scripts.js:
    wp_enqueue_script('myScripts-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_java_scripts');
```

Ok so the **FlexSlider** neeeds **jQuery** and in the last **scripts-js** file I have the following JavaScript:

```
/* Slider */
$(window).load(function() {
 $('#main-slider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     useCSS: false,
     pauseOnHover: true
 });
});
```

I don't know very well jQuery but I think that this script create my FlexSlider slideshow into the **#main-slider** div of my theme, this one (correct me if I am wrong):

```
<div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
</div>
```

The problem is that if I execute the previous scripts into a simple pure HTML website all work well but if I put these scripts into a WP theme the slide show is not shown

After a few hours of panic I found this documentation about the **jQuery no conflict mode in WP**:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

So I have change the previous script that create my slideshow in this way (replacing the $ with the explicit jQuery function):

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
 jQuery('#main-slider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     useCSS: false,
     pauseOnHover: true
 });
});
```

and now all work fine and the slideshow is shown.

Reading the jQuery documentation related to how avoid conflict(http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) it seems to me that exist some other JavaScript framework different from jQuery that also use the **$** character and that the safe mode disable the use of **$** to avoid interpretation conflicts between Jquery code and other library code. And if I can't use **$** in my code I have to replace it using the explicit namespace**jQuery**.

Ok, in this WP documentations: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

show how continue to use $ even if jQuery is set in safe mode, and it do the following example:

**ORIGINAL JQUERY FUNCTION THAT USE $**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(#somefunction) ...
});
```

This function can't work if jQuery is setted in safe mode

So if I want to use **$** and I don't want replace all **$** with **jQuery** in my code I can do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

So it means that I have to replace the first **$** (before my ready() function) and the pass the $ symbol as parameter on my definied function, so in this function I can still use $ without replace it? Is this one the correct meaning?

Comment: May be this should help you? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress

Comment: @sri ok perfet, it is what I search ;-)