# Add title and caption to thumbnail image on mouseover

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to add a simple mouseover image to display the images title and caption data.
I've added the js in my scripts file which is being called okay yet the rollover is not working.

Essentially I want to replicate this page I created as a static site within a WordPress template page.
http://gloucesterweddingphotographer.com/portfolio.php to work on my wordpress portfolio page.
The code block that has the thumbnails is;

```
            <div class="row">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="float: left" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">     
                <div class="thumbnail"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <!--<p>Add venue tag</p>-->
                    </div></a>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured-portfolio' ); ?></a>
                </div>
          </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div><!--End Row-->
```

which outputs;

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="float: left" id="post-485">     
                <div class="thumbnail"><a href="http://stevanbarry.com/dan-wp/portfolio/dan-and-steve/">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4>Dan and Steve</h4>
                        <!--<p>Add venue tag</p>-->
                    </div></a>
                    <a href="http://stevanbarry.com/dan-wp/portfolio/dan-and-steve/"><img src="http://stevanbarry.com/dan-wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Sinead-and-Dave-61-355x237.jpg" class="attachment-wpbs-featured-portfolio wp-post-image" alt="Sinead and Dave 6" /></a>
                </div>
```

The javascript is;

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

//overlay on gallery
$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();

$('.thumbnail').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
    }
);
});
```

Okay Ive managed to add the above to the wordpress page but the CSS is now messed up as the html in wordpress is different. I need to match up the above code to what wordpress outputs below;

```
<div class="col-md-4">

<h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
<h3>View my latest work</h3>
<hr />
<div class="thumbnail">
[caption id="attachment_614" align="aligncenter" width="150"]

<a href="portfolio">
<img class="wp-image-614 size-thumbnail" src="http://localhost/wordpress/dan-morris/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/11/2015-01-15_0002-150x150.jpg" alt="portfolio thumbnail" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<div class="caption">
This is the caption I want[/caption]</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please come up with an [edit], some code and detail. And honestly: Your question is about JavaScript, but your are tagging it with _php_ ? :)

Comment: The js file i'm calling the rollover script is found at the bottom of this file - http://stevanbarry.com/dan-wp/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/library/js/scripts.js?ver=1.2

Comment: This is the page in question I want the rollovers to work - http://gloucesterweddingphotographer.com/portfolio.php

Comment: Please read about how this site works, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174225/add-title-and-caption-to-thumbnail-image-on-mouseover# and follow kaisers advice.

Comment: I have used stack exchange a while (not wordpress site). Ive updated my post.

Comment: @Stephen Again: Please add the relevant code (in that case your JavaScript) into your question. Imagine the following: Someone has the same problem as you, comes to this site, searches for his problem and stumbles upon your question. When reading your question s/he follows the link to the JS on your site and finds **the fixed file**, but nothing to compare to her/his own problem. So as long as you don't add the script into the question, your question won't provide any help for later visitors. I'm closing it and it will cast an automatic reopen vote when you edited it. Will reopen then.

Comment: Apologies ive added the js.

Comment: @Stephen Have you seen [$ not defined using jQuery in Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2895/73)?

Comment: Appreciate that - yes when I added the js to scripts.js file I took it out. I have the script working okay as static html yet my problem is how I use the caption data in wordpress to output on it. I'll update my code block and give an example.