# Is dynamic forms/entries possible in Widget?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, widgets, backbone

I am new to WordPress Plugins development, and I just started working with the widget. My question is: What are the limitations of WordPress Widget?

I tried to use jQuery to make the Widget Form more interactive/dynamic, but it doesn't seem to work at all. For example, I have a button that when clicked will add a string of "Hello!" to a div that has id "here".

```
<div id="here"></div> 
<input type="button" id="add" value="Click Me!" " />

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
             //call when the button is click
             $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
                  $('#here').append('<p>Hello</p>');
             });
        });


</script>
```

1. Why doesn't the paragraph of "Hello" show up on the form? Is it because widget form prevent it from doing so?
2. I also heard about Backbone.js that refreshes the front-end, but I am not sure if that will work.
3. If possible, please explain how the whole wordpress widget class work. Thank you in advance!

**Update: I already tried what are suggested, but it still doesn't work. Here are my code.**

**repeat.php**

```
     <?php
    /**
     * Plugin Name: Repeat Field
     *
     */



     class repeat_field_widget extends WP_Widget {

        /**
         * Sets up the widgets name etc
         */
        public function __construct() {
            $widget_ops = array(
                'classname' => 'repeat_field_widget',
                'description' => 'Repeat Field for Name input',
            );
            parent::__construct( 'repeat_field_widget', 'Repeat Field', $widget_ops );
        }

        /**
         * Outputs the content of the widget
         *
         * @param array $args
         * @param array $instance
         */
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            // outputs the content of the widget
        }

        /**
         * Outputs the options form on admin
         *
         * @param array $instance The widget options
         */
        public function form( $instance ) {
            // outputs the options form on admin
    ?>
        <div id="here"></div>
        <input type="button" id="addRepeat" value="Click Me!" />

      <?php
        }

        /**
         * Processing widget options on save
         *
         * @param array $new_instance The new options
         * @param array $old_instance The previous options
         */
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            // processes widget options to be saved
        }
    }


    function register_repeat_field_widget() {
        register_widget( 'repeat_field_widget' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_repeat_field_widget' );

    function repeat_field_widget_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'repeat-field-widget-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/repeat.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'repeat_field_widget_scripts' );
```

**repeat.js**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       //call when the button is click
       $("#addRepeat").click(function() {
           $('#here').append('<p>Hello</p>');
       });
    });
```

Comment: Look at your console for the error, then read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress).

Comment: In addition to what @toscho said, don't use HTML ids (or at least ids that are not unique). There can be multiple instances of a single widget on one sidebar, and if they have the same ids the HTML will be invalid and JavaScript functionality that depends on IDs could break.

Comment: Thank you very much for response. I tried what you guys suggested, but it still doesn't show up.

Comment: Your question asks about the limits of Widgets, a vague and unanswerable thing, then goes into a specific problem. You should edit your question to focus on your problem, that of how do you run javascript on a widget form. Keep in mind that your widget will need to work in the customizer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you **Dave Romsey** and **Mark Kaplun** for pointing out about not using HTML ID in WordPress Widget. I finally find a solution for my need.

**Solution:**

We need to add a preset variables into all of the 3 functions (widget, form, update). In my codes, they are called "spotlight_image_link1, spotlight_image_link2, etc". Then in the "form function" give their id using php code. Please read my code below for more information.

**What can my solution do?**

Basically, it is not fully dynamic because we need to predefine all the spotlights beforehand. In my case, I only predefined two spotlights to make the code simple to read.

**Here what it looks like:** 
[image]

**Logic behind the scene:**

- whenever the "Click me!" button is clicked, a spotlight will be added.
- There is a tracker array called "tracker" that keep track of which predefined spotlights are already used. When all spotlights are used, disable the "Click me!" button.
- When the "delete spotlight" is clicked, remove that specific spotlight, and re-enable the "Click me!" button. Note that the name of each delete button is append with number. This lets us know which spotlight to be deleted.
- The spotlight is saved only if and only if the input is not empty. That condition is in the "while" loop of the "form" function.

**Limitation:**

As of now, whenever, we clicked "Save", the spotlight order is rearranged from 1 to n. It's not super user-friendly, but I plan to use Ajax to sync the front-end to the back-end. I am not sure how just yet.

**Source code:**

- As of WordPress 4.7.2, it works without any error.
- Put all the source code into "repeat.php" file in your plugin directory. If you don't know how, please google it.

**repeat.php**

```
    <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Repeat Field
 *
 */

 class repeat_field_widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Sets up the widgets name etc
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname' => 'repeat_field_widget',
            'description' => 'Repeat Field for Name input'
        );
        parent::__construct( 'repeat_field_widget', 'Repeat Field', $widget_ops );
    $tracker1;
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content of the widget
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @param array $instance
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // outputs the content of the widget
    $spotlight_add_row = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_add_row'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_add_row'] : '';
    $spotlight_row_appender = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_row_appender'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_row_appender'] : '';

    /**============== Spotlight 1 =========================*/
    $spotlight_image_link1 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_image_link1'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_image_link1'] : '';
    $spotlight_add_image1 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_add_image1'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_add_image1'] : '';
    $spotlight_image_preview1 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_image_preview1'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_image_preview1'] : '';
    $spotlight_name1 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_name1'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_name1'] : '';
    $spotlight_description1 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_description1'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_description1'] : '';
    $spotlight_link1 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_link1'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_link1'] : '';

    /**============== Spotlight 2 =========================*/
    $spotlight_image_link2 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_image_link2'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_image_link2'] : '';
    $spotlight_add_image2 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_add_image2'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_add_image2'] : '';
    $spotlight_image_preview2 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_image_preview2'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_image_preview2'] : '';
    $spotlight_name2 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_name2'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_name2'] : '';
    $spotlight_description2 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_description2'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_description2'] : '';
    $spotlight_link2 = ! empty( $instance['spotlight_link2'] ) ? $instance['spotlight_link2'] : '';
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the options form on admin
     *
     * @param array $instance The widget options
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        // outputs the options form on admin
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'spotlight_add_row' => '', 'spotlight_row_appender' => '', 'spotlight_image_link1' => '', 'spotlight_add_image1' => '', 'spotlight_image_preview1' => '', 'spotlight_name1' => '', 'spotlight_description1' => '', 'spotlight_link1' => '',
    'spotlight_image_link2' => '', 'spotlight_add_image2' => '', 'spotlight_image_preview2' => '', 'spotlight_name2' => '', 'spotlight_description2' => '', 'spotlight_link2' => '' ));

    //Create Add and delete button
    $spotlight_add_row = $instance['spotlight_add_row'];
    $spotlight_row_appender = $instance['spotlight_row_appender'];

    /**================== Spotlight 1 ==============*/
    $spotlight_image_link1 = $instance['spotlight_image_link1'];
    $spotlight_add_image1 = $instance['spotlight_add_image1'];
    $spotlight_image_preview1 = $instance['spotlight_image_preview1'];
    $spotlight_name1 = $instance['spotlight_name1'];
    $spotlight_description1 = $instance['spotlight_description1'];
    $spotlight_link1 = $instance['spotlight_link1'];

    /**================== Spotlight 2 ==============*/
    $spotlight_image_link2 = $instance['spotlight_image_link2'];
    $spotlight_add_image2 = $instance['spotlight_add_image2'];
    $spotlight_image_preview2 = $instance['spotlight_image_preview2'];
    $spotlight_name2 = $instance['spotlight_name2'];
    $spotlight_description2 = $instance['spotlight_description2'];
    $spotlight_link2 = $instance['spotlight_link2'];

    $starter = 1; //Store which number to continue adding spotlight.
    $num = 1;
    $max_spotlight = 2; //number of spotlight allowed.
    static $tracker = array(0,0); //setup a tracker for each spotlight, zero mean none active.

    while($num <= $max_spotlight){
      $tempImage = 'spotlight_image_link' . $num;

       if ($$tempImage != ''){
        $starter++;
        $tracker[$num - 1] = 1;
?>
        <!-- Image input -->
        <div>
        <p class="spotlight-para">Spotlight <?php echo $num; ?></p>
        <p> <?php $tempImage = 'spotlight_image_link' . $num;  $tempDeleteName = 'deletespotlight_'. $num;?> <!-- store the combined name. -->
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( $tempImage ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Image\'s link:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label>
            <input
                   class="widefat"
                   id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($tempImage); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name($tempImage); ?>"
                   type="text"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr($$tempImage); ?>"
                   />
           <input style="float:right;" id="delete-spotlight" name="<?php echo $tempDeleteName; ?>" type="button" value="Delete Spotlight" class="button"/>
           <br />
        </p>
        </div>
<?php
      }
     $num++;
    }
    $id_prefix = $this->get_field_id(''); //get the widget prefix id.
?>
    <span id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('spotlight_row_appender'); ?>"> </span>
    <div>
      <br />
      <input
            class="button"
            type="button"
            id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('spotlight_add_row'); ?>"
            value="Click Me!"
            onclick="repeater.uploader('<?php echo $this->id;?>', '<?php echo $id_prefix;?>'); return false;"
            />
    </div>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      var tracker = <?php echo json_encode($tracker); ?>;
      var c1 = <?php echo json_encode($starter - 1); ?>;//index of the array.

      //disbale add button when reaches max spotlight.
      if(tracker.every(x => x > 0)){
        $('#' + '<?php echo $id_prefix; ?>' + 'spotlight_add_row').attr("disabled",true);
      }

      repeater = {
          //TRY to mass Number into this function........
          uploader :function(widget_id, widget_id_string){
            //Find the non active element
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < <?php echo $max_spotlight; ?>; i++){
              if ( tracker[i] == 0){
                c1 = i;
                break;
              }
            }
            c1++;
            //alert(c1);



            $("#" + widget_id_string + "spotlight_row_appender").append('<div> <p class="spotlight-para">Spotlight '+c1+'</p><p> <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( "spotlight_image_link'+c1+'")); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Image\'s link:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label>  <input  class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id("spotlight_image_link'+c1+'"); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name("spotlight_image_link'+c1+'"); ?>" type="text" value="" />  <input style="float:right;"id="delete-spotlight" name="deletespotlight_'+c1+'" type="button" value="Delete Spotlight" class="button"/><br /> </p></div>');
            //check element as active
            tracker[c1-1] = 1;

            //if all element is > 0, disable the deleteButton.
            if(tracker.every(x => x > 0)){
              $('#' + '<?php echo $id_prefix; ?>' + 'spotlight_add_row').attr("disabled",true);
            }
            //alert(c1);
            return false;
          }
      };

      $(document).on('click', '#delete-spotlight', function() {

        $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //remove the field.
        $('#' + '<?php echo $id_prefix; ?>' + 'spotlight_add_row').removeAttr("disabled"); //reset add button.

        //Get the name, and parse to get the ID.
        var deleteButtonName = this.name;
        var stringDeleteButton = deleteButtonName.split("_").pop();
        var deleteButtonID = parseInt(stringDeleteButton);

        tracker[deleteButtonID-1] = 0; //reset element
        //alert(tracker);
      });

    });
    </script>
  <?php
    }

    /**
     * Processing widget options on save
     *
     * @param array $new_instance The new options
     * @param array $old_instance The previous options
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // processes widget options to be saved
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['spotlight_add_row'] = sanitize_text_field($new_instance['spotlight_add_row']);
    $instance['spotlight_row_appender'] = sanitize_text_field($new_instance['spotlight_row_appender']);

    $increment = 1;
    while ( $increment <= 2 ){
      //increment variables
      $increment_image_link = 'spotlight_image_link' . $increment;
      $increment_add_image = 'spotlight_add_image' . $increment;
      $increment_image_preview = 'spotlight_image_preview' . $increment;
      $increment_description = 'spotlight_description' . $increment;
      $increment_name = 'spotlight_name' . $increment;
      $increment_link = 'spotlight_link' . $increment;

      $instance[$increment_image_link] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance[$increment_image_link] );
      $instance[$increment_add_image] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance[$increment_add_image] );
      $instance[$increment_image_preview] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance[$increment_image_preview]);
      $instance[$increment_name] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance[$increment_name] );
      $instance[$increment_description] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance[$increment_description] );
      $instance[$increment_link] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance[$increment_link] );

      $increment++;
    }
    $starter = 1;
    $num = 1;

    return $instance;
    }
}


function register_repeat_field_widget() {
    register_widget( 'repeat_field_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_repeat_field_widget' );
```

**Quick Note:**

I know that this is not the most clean, secure, and best code, but I am still learning. I hope that helps anyone who faces the same issues as me.

Answer (score 1):

Widget forms are tricky for JS manipulation. In general you should never use IDs to detect elements in the form, but a combination of classes and `find()`, `parent()` etc.

The reason is that there might be more than one form on the HTML page. For sure on the widget admin page there is a "template" form that is not displayed and IIRC is used to generate the form for a new widget. This means that there will be at least two element with the same ID, and an attempt to access them by DOM APIs will not give a consistent result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please elaborate a little of how to use "Classes, find(), parent()"  in the widget form?

Comment: IDs are required to be unique to be valid HTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id