# Basic Wordpress AJAX Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I have a fresh WP install and for purposes of keeping things simple I currently just have a simple action as follows in my `functions.php`:

```
function getFruits() {
    return json_encode( ['fruits' => ['apples', 'pears']]);
} 

function my_enqueue() {    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Now, my objective is to use JQuery / JavaScript to make an AJAX call to my wordpress endpoint and get the fruits json object back and print it console simply when rendering the landing page.

This is what I tried:

`twentyseventeen\js\my-ajax-script.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "get",
            data : {
                action: 'getFruits'
            },
            dataType: "json",
            url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg); //output fruits to console
            }
        });
});
```

Currently, I am getting a JQuery is not defined error, although it seems to be enqueued. Second, I am not sure I am even implementing this correctly as I never used WP AJAX before. So right now, my objective is just to get a basic example working. I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Thank you

Comment: One of your issues is a common one - WordPress jQuery is in noConflict mode, meaning there's no `$` alias to begin with. You need to do something like [these answers suggest](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2895/7355). What is you action hook code?

Comment: Hey there, yes! that worked for resolving the jquery not found error but still not getting the array of fruits back. Now I am getting a 0 response printed to console. I appreciate the help :) Not sure what you mean by action hook code... All the code I added following a fresh WP install is posted above, everything else is default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress AJAX uses actions to connect your jQuery `action` with a traditional WordPress action. Take a look at the [example WordPress provides in their docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). There's 2 hooks:

```
add_action( "wp_ajax_{$jquery_action_string}", "callback_function_name" );
```

The above will only work for authenticated ( logged in ) users. For non-logged-in users we use `nopriv`:

```
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_{$jquery_action_string}", "callback_function_name" );
```

So in our case we would use both:

```
function return_fruits() {
    echo json_encode( ['fruits' => ['apples', 'pears']]);
    exit();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getFruits', 'return_fruits' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getFruits', 'return_fruits' );
```

Note, I changed your call back function name to identify that the ajax action and the callback name do not need to be identical. Also note, you would want to **echo** this data instead of return it.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but why echo instead of return?

Comment: @rudtek While using `wp_ajax_*` I don't believe you can return and have to echo but I cannot tell you why off the top of my head. This may be a good question on it's own if it hasn't already been asked on the site!

Comment: Can you help me out here? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/359762/52859

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ajax action hook to perform your jquery action.

for login user:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_getFruits', 'getFruits);
```

for not login user:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getFruits', 'getFruits');

function get_fruits(){
$response = array('Fruits'=> ['banana', 'apple']);
//use this function and make a response then send the response
wp_send_json_success(array('response'=>$response));
// by using wp_send_json_success() you don't need to exit and parse response
}
```