# simple wordpress ajax plugin not working when not logged in

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax, mysql

anyone encountered this bug that it will work when you are logged in but once you log out it won't work anymore.

this is a very simple plugin that will fetch zip code and display the corresponding rate.

here's the code. https://pastebin.com/TPFYJFCP

TIA!

Comment: You are missing the `nopriv` action if you want to allow access for non logged in users. See here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277343/basic-wordpress-ajax-call/277346#277346

Comment: I will try on this @czerspalace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`wp_ajax_nopriv_`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) for handling ajax for non-authenticated users:

```
// logged-out users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_search_key_press', 'action_search_key_press_callback' );

// authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action_search_key_press', 'action_search_key_press_callback' );
```

Comment: UPDATE: it works now, tested on incognito as well and even with other browsers.