# Ajax call works for logged in users and returns "Bad Request" for guests

Tags: ajax, actions, json

I have a WordPress site that uses ajax to submit a form on the Front-end.

When the form is submitted by a logged-in user, all works fine.
When the form is submitted by not-logged-in user, I get a "Bad Request" error.

Here is my code:

**JS:**

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Submit the POST request
    $.ajax({
        url: jsobject.ajaxurl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'fe_submit_form'
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
function fe_submit_form() {
    ...
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fe_submit_form', 'fe_submit_form' );
```

When the user is logged in, all works fine.
When the user is not logged it, I never go inside of the "fe_submit_form" php function.

Any ideas?

Comment: The following question may point you in the right direction: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/280607/simple-wordpress-ajax-plugin-not-working-when-not-logged-in . Also, you should review the WordPress documentation on AJAX https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action for non-logged in users is `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}`.