# JavaScript: TypeError: xyz is not a function after upgrading WordPress

Tags: javascript

After upgrading WordPress from 4.9.13 to 5.3.2 some scripts on website stop working in weird way... (example for clndr.js).

All scripts are added via `wp_register_script` and `wp_add_inline_script` WordPress' functions.

At bottom of `<body>` there are three scripts as always:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/clndr.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/calendar.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var calendar = create_calendar();
</script>
```

Relevant part of `calendar.js`

```js
function create_calendar()
{
    var calendar = $('#Calendar').clndr({
        // clndr options
    });

    return calendar;
}
```

All scripts should run in right order, but they are not working and in browser console I have this error:
`TypeError: $(...).clndr is not a function`

Also, changing call to `create_calendar` in this way:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var calendar = create_calendar();
});
```

changes only order of errors in console.

If I understand everything correctly, this should just work..
Any ideas? Or hints how to debug this?

Comment: jQuery isn't available as `$` in WordPress. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress

Comment: Nice hint. I have custom jQuery included from beginning. Removing WordPress' one as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27048128 fix all problems... They must change something, maybe naming of jQuery script handle..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [@fuxia](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/fuxia) comment:

Solution is removing jQuery included by WordPress just before register/enqueue custom jQuery (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27048128).

So if you include some jQuery on your own, then add

```php
wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

just before register/enqueue custom jQuery script in `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

**Or** if you want jQuery included by WordPress just remember, that it's in no-conflict mode and `$` is undefined.
See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2896/182809 for more details.

Comment: -1 for what exacly?