# Fade-in Fade-out doesn't work in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have back-to-top script with an arrow icon which appears when scrolling down and disappears when the page content is on top. Works perfect, but when I insert the script in Wordpress the `scrollTop` part of the script works but not the `fade-in` and `fade-out` effect.

Any solution?

```js
(function($) {

$('body').prepend('<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>');
var amountScrolled = 300;
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ( $(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled ) {
    $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
} else {
    $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
}
});

$('a.back-to-top, a.simple-back-to-top').click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 700);
return false;
});

}(jQuery));
```

```css
body {background:#FEF1D4; height:1000px}

.back-to-top {
    display: none;
    width: 4.75rem;
    height: 4.75rem;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1500;
    left: 0.5rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
    background: url(https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1920879-200.png) no-repeat center 43%;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Expected result → [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielillo/79s2rnta/)

Wordpress result ↓

[image]

Comment: Did you read https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress?

Comment: I already tried but with a same result

Comment: Then update the code in your question please, and tell us what you see in the error console.

Comment: Code updated, in the question and in the jsfiddle. The error console doesn't say anything. Maybe is a conflict with some of the theme scripts.

Comment: You appear to be loading jQuery from an external CDN. You might be running into conflicts with WordPress's bundled version of jQuery.

Comment: After a deep cleaning, deleting the CDN and following all [this steps](https://nimblewebdeveloper.com/blog/use-modern-jquery-in-wordpress) the problem persists.